# Change AD users attributes via Power Shell script

Tags: active-directory, powershell, user-accounts, organizational-unit, attributes

In the domain I'm working we created an attribute "**regulationMatrix**" . When I try a powershell command like **get-aduser USER -properties *** that specific attribute shows up only if it has a value set like "**regulationMatrix                   : {PIC}**", if not it doesn't appear on the output.

The attribute was recently added and now i have to add this attribute to 1000 users from a single OU.

Could someone help me with a script or command for example to modify the attributes to all users from the specific OU.

Thank you.

```
    $userlist = get-aduser -searchbase "OU=RandomOU,DC=contoso,DC=europa,DC=net" -filter * -properties regulationMatrix
foreach ( $users in $userlist ) {
    $username = $users.samaccountname
    $reg = $users.regulationmatrix
    write-host $username
    write-host $reg

set-aduser -identity $username -add @{'regulationMatrix'='PIC'}
            }
```

Thanks to Daniel i figured what to add, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example for a single user. Use filters or otherwise get a list of users, explicitly request the *regulationMatrix* property and then pipe the whole thing into the `Set-ADUser`command. Use `-Replace` or `-Add` to modify the property.

```
Get-ADUser j.doe -Properties regulationMatrix | Set-ADUser -Replace @{regulationMatrix="Hurz"}
```